# Map-Reduce : How to count in a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce, reduce

Important edit : **I can't use `filter`** - the purpose is pedagogic.

I have an array in which I would want to count the number of its elements that verify a boolean, using only `map` and `reduce`.

## Count of the array's size

I already wrote something that counts the array's size (ie. : the number of **all** of its elements), using `reduce` :

```
const array_numbers = [12, 15, 1, 1]; // Size : 4
console.log(
              array_numbers.reduce((acc) => {
                return acc + 1;
              }, 0)
);
```

## Count of the array's elements checking a boolean condition

Now I would want to count only the elements that verify a boolean condition. Thus, I must use `map` before `reduce` and the elements of the `map`'s returned array will be only the good elements.

**So I wrote this code but it doesn't work...** Indeed, I put `null` when I encounter a not-good element (and `null` is counted as en element unfortunately).

*NB : here, the boolean condition is "is the element even ? (%2 == 0)".*

```
const array_numbers = [12, 15, 1, 1]; // Size : 4
console.log(
              array_numbers.map((current_value) => {
                if(current_value % 2 == 0) {
                  return current_value;
                }
                return null;

              }).reduce((acc) => {
                return acc + 1;

              }, 0)
);
```

Comment: you're looking for `filter`....

Comment: I know, but I must recreate this function - it's pedagogic in fact.

Comment: See my answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#filter` the array and check the length:

```js
const array_numbers = [12, 15, 1, 1];
const result = array_numbers.filter((n) => n % 2 === 0).length;

console.log(result);
```

Or count using `Array#reduce`:

```js
const array_numbers = [12, 15, 1, 1, 4];
const result = array_numbers.reduce((r, n) => n % 2 ? r : r + 1, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Or if you must, you can use `Array#map` with `Array#reduce`:

```js
const array_numbers = [12, 15, 1, 1, 4];
const result = array_numbers
  .map((n) => n % 2 === 0 ? 1 : 0) // map to 1 or 0 according to the condition
  .reduce((r, n) => r + n); // sum everything

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use `filter` (pedagogic exercise). I modified the OP to indicate this. Sorry =/

Comment: I've added an answer with reduce.

Comment: Aaah I didn't think to use `reduce` like that, thank you !

Comment: I've added another one with map and reduce for the sake of it.

Comment: Thank you again. :) Do you know if it's possible to use only `map` if I want to verify that all elements verify the boolean condition ? (so it's a bit different)

Comment: You can map all elements to `true` or `false`, and then check that everything `true` using `every` or `reduce`.

Comment: Ah tank you, and tell me if i am wrong but using only `reduce` is not possible (because it returns either `true` or `false` and the accumulator value, if set at `false`, should not change to `true` - the below code is thus wrong : `array_numbers.reduce((acc, current_value) => {
      if(current_value % 2 != 0) {
        return false;
      } else { return true;}
    }, true)`

Comment: Indeed. I wrote this : `array_numbers.reduce((acc, current_value) => {
      return acc || (current_value % 2 == 0)
    }, false)` to verify if at least one element is even (inspired by you) ; it seems to work fine, could you confirm please ? :)

Comment: It works. My previous comment has a mistake. I should've initialized it with a `true`.

Comment: Array#reduce is even simpler. The accumulator can be a Boolean as well - array_numbers.reduce((acc, current_value) => acc && (current_value % 2) === 0, true);

Comment: Ahah yes thank you ^^ Do you know when is `map` useful for these kinds of "programs" (so to work with collection) ? because in fact, `reduce` is really powerful and seems to be able to replace `map` anywhere.. =/

Comment: `reduce` is a swiss knife, while `map` and `filter` are targeted for specific situation. This is a good time to do some reading. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the *even* numbers - and you don't need the `reduce()` function - you can use `length` of the array returned by the `filter()` function.

Or you can use `reduce()` method alone like below:

See demos below:

```js
const array_numbers = [12, 15, 1, 1]; // Size : 4

// using filter
console.log(
  array_numbers.filter((current_value) => {
    return current_value % 2 == 0;
  }).length
);

// using reduce
console.log(
  array_numbers.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return curr % 2 == 0 ? prev + 1 : prev;
  }, 0)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use filter (pedagogic exercise). I modified the OP to indicate this. Sorry =/

Answer (score 2):

As Jared Smith mentioned, you don't need to use `map` for this task. 
`Array.reduce()` gets the current element as a second argument in the callback function which you can use to check if it satisfies your given condition.

So, again assuming that you *must* use either `map` and/or `reduce`:

```js
const myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const condition = function(a) {
  // let's say
  return a %2 == 0;
}

let result = myArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return condition(val) ? acc + 1 : acc
  }, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since per your comment you *must* use reduce for some reason:

```
arr.reduce((acc, n) => { n % 2 ? acc + n : acc }, 0);
```

The map is unecessary.

Comment: Aaah I didn't think to use `reduce` like that, thank you !

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler if you're satisfied please accept :)